# AngularJS Linky produces security error when processing broken URL in IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm displaying URL after formatting them by applying Linky filter, when I tested this with a broken URL its produces security error in IE(Checked in IE11).

It works fine in Chrome and Mozilla.

**Angular Version**: 1.2.29

**Broken URL used**: http://@gmail.com

**Error**

> Error: A security problem occurred.
>
> at xa
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js:124:230)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js:116:319)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.js:145:9)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.js:461:11)
>   at r
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js:7:390)
>   at start
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.js:458:9)
>   at parseStartTag
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.js:363:24)
>   at htmlParser
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.js:293:13)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sanitize.js:144:7)
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular-sa

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a workaround @Mathankumar?

Comment: It is explained more deeper here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834489